# COMPASS CREATE Permissions denied

Tags: ruby, windows, compass-sass

I have gem installed both SASS and COMPASS using

```
gem install compass
```

I am trying to use the command

```
compass create .
```

to generate a compass project but when i do I get the following error.

```
Errno::EACCES on line ["897"] of C: Permission denied
```

This appears as it is trying to create the **config.rb** file
I am at a bit of a loss as it seems to be able to create both the **stylesheets** and **sass** directories

```
PS C:\Projects\tutorials\sass> compass create --trace
create config.rb
Errno::EACCES on line ["897"] of C: Permission denied - (C:/Projects/tutorials/sass/config.rb20140323-9028-1j0o9n1, C:/P
rojects/tutorials/sass/config.rb)
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.18/lib/sass/util.rb:897:in `atomic_create_and_write_file'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.4/lib/compass/actions.rb:58:in `write_file'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.4/lib/compass/app_integration/stand_alone/installer.rb:20:in `write_c
onfiguration_files'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.4/lib/compass/app_integration/stand_alone/installer.rb:35:in `prepare
'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.4/lib/compass/installers/base.rb:32:in    `run'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-.12.4/lib/c ompass/commands/stamp_pattern.rb:75:in `perform'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.4/lib/compass/commands/base.rb:18:in `execute'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.4/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:19:in `execute'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.4/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:43:in `perform!'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.4/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:15:in `run!'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.4/bin/compass:30:in `block in <top   (required)>'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.4/bin/compass:44:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.4/bin/compass:44:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby193/bin/compass:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby193/bin/compass:23:in `<main>'
```

any help anyone could give me to resolve this would be most appreciated

Comment: I'm having very similar issues after updating yesterday, what versions of software and OS are you on?

Comment: I have another machine and I performed the same install with success on that machine very confused

Comment: I am on a windows 8.1 machine

Comment: Try uninstalling compass and sass and the re-installed with the --pre option, as detailed by the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22596760/yeoman-error-errnoeacces-on-line-897-of-c-permission-denied/22597296#22597296 I was having the same problem and this fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this issue by downgrading the compass version. then i've tryed to understand what was the error. 
So the problem was version conflicts between sass 3.2.14 and 3.3.4 . compass 0.12.3 depends on 3.2.14 sass verison.
Have a look at this link [Can't get sass + compass + susy installed due to version conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22299466/cant-get-sass-compass-susy-installed-on-osx-due-to-version-conflict)

If you want to make things work with the latest compass version. you can uninstall all sass  and compass version that you have. then look for the appropriate version between them.
This will things work perfectly. 
And as a better solution you can work with this : http://bundler.io/ .

Kind regards.

Comment: Thank you uninstalling everything and installing with the --pre command has solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

you're right. and here you can find details about this issue: https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/1618#issuecomment-38397775
They are working to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the issue in the util.rb file specified in the error, an attempt is made to change the permissions of the files I think this link may hold the answer.

[stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933228/ruby-fileutils-chmod-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this way :

```
  gem install compass -v 0.12.3 --no-rdoc --no-ri
```

and install :

```
  compass install blueprint
```

it work for me